# Alignment Change from Left to Right for String Column Values in CSV Generated by SQR

Tags: csv, sqr

I have generated a csv file using SQR and output commes as left align by default for string. I need to make it right align. Please suggest.

For example:

address 
xxx 
yyy 
zzz

i need

address 
    xxx 
    yyy 
    zzz

code used to write CSV is

write $address

Please assist on this.

Comment: I don't quite understand the right-align part - you mean left blank fill?  If so, you could use the RPAD function to right align it.  However, if you mean right-aligning in the CSV file when you open it up, you're out of luck because Excel will pretty much left justify it and all the blanks will be squashed.  Exactly why do you need it right-aligned?

Comment: Your example matches your statement of what you need. I would love to help but I don't understand what you are looking for.